# Certbot: where is packaged automatic renewal cron job?

Tags: cron, lets-encrypt, certbot

As per [Certbot documentation for Ubuntu 16.04](https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions/#ubuntu-16-04-xenial-none-of-the-above) and other distros, there is supposedly installed with the package a cron job that will automatically renew certificates:

> The **Certbot packages on your system come with a cron job that will
>   renew your certificates automatically before they expire.** Since Let's
>   Encrypt certificates last for 90 days, it's highly advisable to take
>   advantage of this feature.

However I cannot find any related documentation on this subject, and I cannot find any cron job configured on crontab after following certbot installation instructions on the same page (version 0.19.0). Does this feature really exists? If yes, how to find it and configure it?

*Note: I found this piece of doc when trying to configure automatic renewal with hooks. I could manually configure a cron job but using a built-in automated renewal feature seems more appropriate.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 (among others) automatic renewal is handled by systemd instead of cron:

```
foo@localhost:~# systemctl list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED    UNIT                         ACTI
Fri 2018-05-25 19:05:59 UTC  1min 25s left n/a                          n/a       systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer syst
Sat 2018-05-26 00:56:58 UTC  5h 52min left Fri 2018-05-25 12:13:30 UTC  6h ago    certbot.timer                cert
Sat 2018-05-26 06:17:45 UTC  11h left      Fri 2018-05-25 06:42:23 UTC  12h ago   apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-
Sat 2018-05-26 12:51:39 UTC  17h left      Fri 2018-05-25 18:51:08 UTC  13min ago apt-daily.timer              apt-
```

The timer is triggered twice per day by default.

```
foo@localhost:~# cat /lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run certbot twice daily

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00,12:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=3600
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Comment: That's right, I would never have figured that out by myself, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short, try this:
https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot

long:

you have picked an odd timing for setting up ssl with certbot.

There are issues with vulnerabilities sadly. For their old renewal method that is.

so I opened this question here, and it contains some info where you should be looking for answers
[Certbot automatic renewal vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996982/certbot-automatic-renewal-vulnerabilities)