# Certbot automatic renewal vulnerabilities

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have certbot including automatic renewal in use in several installations with clients.

Now I have been reading here:

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2018-01-11-update-regarding-acme-tls-sni-and-shared-hosting-infrastructure/50188

here

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/solution-client-with-the-currently-selected-authenticator-does-not-support-any-combination-of-challenges-that-will-satisfy-the-ca/49983

and here

https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5405

as well here:

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/important-what-you-need-to-know-about-tls-sni-validation-issues/50811

everyone seems to be saying something slightly different

and no clear explanation is given.

I've been reading in the standard description of the certbot installation

Renewal docs point here:

https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewal

but: the old vulnerable `tls-sni-01` method is still listed

I try to summarize:

In the guides to mitigate existing issues on existing servers:

they recommend stop and starting the server on renewal.
But... this is not good. What if some config breaks, and the server gets stop started when I am asleep? The server would be unavailable. Or something worse. I am not an devops expert but having the server more or less randomly start and stop, doesn't seem like a good solution. Am I wrong about this?

As alternative, I see *only* the webroot plugin that does not use `tls-sni-01`. https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot

that seems to be the only way to me, that seems reliable.

Am I missing something? are we basically told to use the webroot plugin?

as all others do use tls-sni-01, are not automated (you can do it manually but ehrm, I actually don't want to) or require you to not have a running server already (standalone).

That is for future servers. I guess existing domain renewals will continue to work with the old `tls-sni-01`, that is what they seem to be saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as I got no answers, I will have to assume that's what it is, e.g. use webroot plugin when possible.

What I actually found out is this:

the command `certbot renew` goes to the folder `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal` and checks the config files there. Those config files get created by the last time you triggered the certification process from command line. So if the last thing you did was use standalone, you will find standalone config there (you want to migrate away from that)

ok so now you run the first time the webroot plugin:

`certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/www.mypage.com/public -d www.mypage.com -d mypage.com` [see here](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot)

this can, eventually, create a new entry in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal` or overwrite the old existing one. Just be sure to delete the standalone one in case it did not overwrite but create a new file, you want only to have the webroot one there

now run `crontab -e` eventually have to be root user

add

`53 14 * * * certbot renew --post-hook "service nginx reload"`

this will run each day at 14:53 and reload the config and try to renew the certificates

Comment: Be careful with the crontab usage, as certbot automatically adds an auto renew cronjob and timer upon installation. Better to add your --post-hook in there so you don't have 2 jobs doing the same thing. More info here: https://gist.github.com/jonasva/be3f89f6a06f80692920b87afbb602bc

Comment: @Jones03 that's interesting information... please add an answer I can transfer the accepted answer to you (I think). I don't quite entirely understand your instructions btw. E.g. `Once you've established that the timer is running` not sure how to make sure it is running. You wrote as well, if it is running, it does _not_ execute the cronjob. Bit confused

Comment: @Jones03 I just did a new installation on a new droplet of certbot, using their basic setup and it did a http authentication, e.g. `sudo certbot --nginx` would do http-01 or something like that, not the vulnerable one... confusion complete